# Use Generative model or discriminative model?

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, deep-learning

I spend much time figuring out the differences between generative model and discriminative model, it seems that generative model is more useful because it is capable of more than prediction, but it is said that discriminative model often outperform generative model. So, in which cases we should apply generative model and when turn to discriminative model.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial service.

Comment: The answers here maybe can help you: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/12421/generative-vs-discriminative

Answer (score 0):

A [**generative model**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generative_model) is able to sample from the unterlying distribution. It learns P(x, y).

A [**discriminative model**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminative_model) is able to distinguish classes. It learns P(y|x).

Often, it is not necessary to be able to sample from the distribution. You only need to be able to discriminate. And discriminators are usually simpler to train.